# Implementing a job queue with rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq, job-queue

I have built a rabbitmq wrapper which publishes messages to consumers and this is working well.

Can I also build a work queue (like gearman) in rabbitmq which can distribute long running tasks to consumers and the consumers, in turn, notify the publisher with the results.

I guess this would  require the publisher to act as a consumer as well which I am not sure how to implement. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Or, is rabbitmq just not the tool for such case.

Thanks,

Comment: It may be overkill, but [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) is pretty good at doing what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ supports this type of pattern. Have a look at the [RPC tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html) for a bootstrap of how to implement this pattern.

It can be implemented in different way depending of your needs:

- [direct reply queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html), queue will be created and used only for the reply associated to the request
- static reply queue which will contain all the replies

It usually implies a correlation id to correlate request with the reply, or it can be stateless if the reply contains all the necessary information.

It really depends on your needs.